# Get group of form items by DataLabel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm working on modifying some vba code, mostly adding a new feature to lock some of the form. So I was trying to use the `DataLabel` property for the items. And is looks to be a dead end.

But I hope its possible to group them and perform a group action in the form of enable/disable.

Any ideas on how? pretty open to any idea or solution simpler than disabling one at a time.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question but if you're talking about a group of `Controls` on a `UserForm` then I believe all controls within a `Frame` will be disabled if the `Frame is disabled (and vice versa).

Comment: yes its a form with a bunch of controllers. i want to group some of them and then enable/disable them with a checkbox

Comment: `Frame` might be worth a go then. Add a `Frame` to your `UserForm` and drag all relevant controls onto it. Then in your VBA `Checkbox_Change` event, try `Frame1.Enabled = CheckBox1.Value`. I know this works with `Buttons` but haven't tried anything else.